# Debian 10 MariaDB 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'

Tags: mysql, linux, debian, mariadb, debian-buster

Good evening Community,

I am in despair because I cannot install MariaDB on Debian10. There are similar Stackoverflow questions but none of them helped to solve my problem.

What I've tried:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

So far no errors.

```
$ sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

Leads to:

> Enter current password for root (enter for none):
>   ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>   [systemmd errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNzNY.png)

Searching for the file called "mysqld.sock" doesn't deliver results.

```
$ cd /etc/init.d/
$ mysqld_safe
$ sudo find / -type s | grep mysqld.sock
```

Doesn't deliver any results. It appears that no `mysqld.sock` file has been created.

> Stackoverflow: [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Can anybody please help me with this problem?

Thanks,

milli727

---

Comment: Check if the server is already running $ sudo systemctl status mariadb if not check the logs first.

Comment: @nbk "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."

Comment: @xehpuk docker? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59466250/docker-system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system

Comment: @nbk Nope, WSL.

Comment: aha, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197246/system-has-not-been-booted-with-systemd-as-init-system-pid-1-cant-operate

Answer (score 0):

Not a Linux expert, but learning every day. Had the same thing, installed Mariadb yesterday on a new Debian server. That's what brought me to this question.

First:

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb
```

You will probably find red flags there, and most probably the mariadb service is not running.

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

And again:

```
sudo systemctl status mariadb
```

to test if it runs now.

And IMPORTANT don't forget to enable the service so that the mariadb service will automatically restart after a restart of the server.

```
sudo systemctl enable mariadb
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
systemctl stop mysql
systemctl stop mariadb
chkconfig --del mysql
systemctl disable mysql
systemctl disable mariadb
systemctl enable mariadb.service
systemctl start mariadb.service
```

Comment: This is a very elaborate response, which neither works nor contains available commands.